# Как работает selectionArgs в android и SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite

Почему при использовании selectionArgs меняется результат, вот два аналогичных запроса:

```
rawQuery("SELECT 2 < 1", null);  // результат: 0
rawQuery("SELECT 2 < ?", new String[]{"1"});  // результат: 1
```

Вот пример кода:

```
Cursor cursor = bd.rawQuery("SELECT 2 < 1", null);
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        String value = cursor.getString(0);
        Log.d("test", "Query 1: " + value);
}
cursor.close();


Cursor cursor1 = bd.rawQuery("SELECT 2 < ?", new String[]{"1"});
if (cursor1.moveToFirst()) {
        String value = cursor1.getString(0);
        Log.d("test", "Query 2: " + value);
}
cursor1.close();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не работаю с Андроидом, но погуглив [документацию](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20android.os.CancellationSignal)), нашёл что

> The values will be bound as Strings.

Как можно удостовериться, `SELECT 2 < '1'` выдаёт `1`. Опять же, не знаю, насколько это правильно, но вы можете использовать `CAST`:

```
SELECT 2 < CAST(? AS INTEGER)
```